# Dependency caused MalformedParameterizedTypeException

Tags: maven, wildfly, wildfly-11

I't trying to deploy WAR package in Wildfly 11. Using these POM dependencies I get errors during startup:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.53</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But I get error during start time:

```
    3:05:33,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
    13:05:34,525 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service         
................    
    13:05:34,543 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Sunlex_site.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Sunlex_site.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
        Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
    Exception 0 :
    javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
......    
    "}}
    13:05:34,559 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "Sunlex_site.war" (runtime-name : "Sunlex_site.war")
    13:05:34,562 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
    WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Sunlex_site.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
```

Can you advice how I can fix the issue? I suppose that the problem is related to wrong dependency?

Comment: There should be a stack trace further up the logs.

Comment: And as usual, no response from OP...